# [VBA]Run-time Error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to execute this code it stops with an error

> Run-time Error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set.

And the error is in those lines:

```
 iTotalWords = wordHilite.getNumText
 iTotalWords = PDFJScriptObj.getPageNumWords(Nthpage)
```

I tried to put a break point on that lines but it doesn't work

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FindWord        'Word you want to search
    Dim acroAppObj As Object
    Dim PDFDocObj As Object
    Dim myPDFPageHiliteObj As Object

    Dim iword As Integer
    Dim iTotalWords As Integer
    Dim numOfPage As Integer
    Dim Nthpage As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim sPath As String

    Set acroAppObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set PDFDocObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set myPDFPageHiliteObj = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
    Check3 = myPDFPageHiliteObj.Add(0, 32767)
    FindWord = TextBox1.Value
    acroAppObj.Show
    sPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Erros.pdf"
    PDFDocObj.Open (sPath)

    numOfPage = PDFDocObj.GetNumPages

    word = vbNullString
    Set PDFJScriptObj = Nothing

    For Nthpage = 0 To numOfPage - 1
      Set pAcroPDPage = PDFDocObj.AcquirePage(Nthpage)
      Set wordHilite = pAcroPDPage.CreateWordHilite(myPDFPageHiliteObj)
      Set PDFJScriptObj = PDFDocObj.GetJSObject
       iTotalWords = wordHilite.getNumText
       iTotalWords = PDFJScriptObj.getPageNumWords(Nthpage)
        ''check the each word
        For iword = 0 To iTotalWords - 1
           word = Trim(CStr(PDFJScriptObj.getPageNthWord(Nthpage, iword)))
            If word <> "" Then
                If word = FindWord Then
                    PageNumber = Nthpage
                    MsgBox PageNumber
                End If
                word = ""
            End If
        Next iword
    Next Nthpage
End Sub
```

Comment: The error message is basically telling you that one of the objects on which you are getting a property or invoking a method, is set to nothing.  What I'd do is put a breakpoint on the line giving you the issue and then, when the code stops, inspect the values in your variables.  You'll find that at least one of them is empty.  Then go back to where you have set these variables and work out why they haven't populated

Comment: Check with your debugger if the objects have been properly `Set` and see if you can see members of the objects.

Comment: Try     Set     in both the lines : 
Set iTotalWords = wordHilite.getNumText
Set iTotalWords = PDFJScriptObj.getPageNumWords(Nthpage)

Comment: I tried to put 'Set' in both lines but when I start the program it says that 'object required'.

Comment: This seems to have less to do with Excel then a third-party library you're trying to address. You may want to tag your question better so that it shows up for people using whatever library this is. It sounds like you may not have a reference to the library and that you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your VBA code...

Comment: Any of those 'pieces' could be returning no object. It's quite possible that `getPageNumWords(Nthpage)` is the problem, for example if the page number you pass in is not valid. You need to hover over it in debug mode, as already suggested, to find out exactly which of those four things is returning no object.

Comment: I am rookie on vba, so I have some difficultss. 
When I hover over it in debug mode PageNumber returns 'Empty'. Do you think thar the error is here?